# Delete all comments from Orchard CMS Blog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am having on going issues with spam comments on an Orchard CMS Blog and now the site is running very slow due to the amount of comments trying to be retrieved from the database and then it times out and crashes. I am using Arvixe as shared hosting and in an ideal world I would like to delete all the comments in 1 hit but I can't do this through the CMS as it times out and then I get the access denied message and have to log back in again.

Any ideas what I can do, I assume I could up the memory on the server but this would cost more and is not the solution I want to go with. Is there any way to access the database to remove delete the comments from there?

Comment: Do you have access to run sql queries directly?  Is this in SqlCE?

Comment: I am a front end developer with limited database knowledge so I don't know how to run queries. I do know that the database is SqlCE though.

Comment: You'll have to find out, by asking your hosting company if you can access the database from the outside. I'm afraid the manipulations to do on the database are not going to be trivial. If you have limited knowledge of databases, you should probably hire someone to do it for you. Also, always do a backup before you attempt anything of the sort.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I will get the server memory and query time increased to avoid the time out, that way I can delete all the blog comments in the cms itself, not ideal but the best I can think of.